# Modifying Sub-aggregation dynamically

Tags: elasticsearch

How to modify a sub aggregation dynamically?

```
val nestedAggregation = termsAggregation
      .subAggregation(filterAggregation
         .subAggregation(Sum1Aggregation)
         .subAggregation(Sum2Aggregation)
         .subAggregation(Sum3Aggregation)
       )
```

Is it possible to modify the above nestedAggregation object once it's created?
For example, what if i want to add another aggregation inside filter aggregation after the object is created?

```
nestedAggregation.filterAggregation.subAggregation(Avg1Aggregation) -- This didn't work
```

----- My code ------

```
  val filterAggregation = AggregationBuilders
  .filter(aggName)
  .filter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery
    .must(rangeQuery(fieldName)
      .gte(startDate)
      .lt(endDate)))

 val nestedAggregation = terms1Aggregation
          .subAggregation(filterAggregation
             .subAggregation(Sum1Aggregation)
             .subAggregation(Sum2Aggregation)
             .subAggregation(Sum3Aggregation)
             .subAggregation(Avg1Aggregation)
           )

shouldSortByHours(sortKey) match {
  case true => nestedAggregation
  case false => {
    // This is where am planning to add the avg1 aggregation to filteraggregation
  }
}
```

**Update #2** - [Possible Solution]

```
if (!shouldSortByHours(sortKey)){
        filterAggregation.subAggregation(Avg1Aggregation) 
    }

    val nestedAggregation = activeSubscriptionsList
      .subAggregation(filterAggregation
             .subAggregation(Sum1Aggregation)
             .subAggregation(Sum2Aggregation)
             .subAggregation(Sum3Aggregation)
      )
```

Comment: How about simply `filterAggregation.subAggregation(Avg1Aggregation)`?

Comment: Is that going to create a new nested object?

Comment: It is going to add a new sub-aggregation to the filter aggregation.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain it correctly. What I need at the end is a nested object. There's an if else condition in my code. I want to alter the nested object based on the result of that if condition. Let's say if it evaluates to true, I need that avg aggregation in my nested object inside filter aggregation. Otherwise, don't. I understand that we can modify filteraggregation object but I wanted to know whether we can modify the nested object. Looks like it is not possible once you create the nested object.

Comment: Maybe show your full code with the if condition. Anything is possible, it's just a question of sequencing.

Comment: Can you also add the declaration of `filterAggregation`?

Comment: Updated. I think i got it working by refactoring the code a bit. Can you please take a look at my update #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
var filterAggregation = AggregationBuilders
  .filter(aggName)
  .filter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery
    .must(rangeQuery(fieldName)
      .gte(startDate)
      .lt(endDate)))
  .subAggregation(Sum1Aggregation)
  .subAggregation(Sum2Aggregation)
  .subAggregation(Sum3Aggregation)

shouldSortByHours(sortKey) match {
  case true => {
      terms1Aggregation.subAggregation(filterAggregation)
  }
  case false => {
      filterAggregation.subAggregation(Avg1Aggregation)
      terms1Aggregation.subAggregation(filterAggregation)
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the code in your second update should work, too

Comment: yep, makes sense. Thanks for the help :)